# Replacement of sun.misc.BASE64Encoder in Oracle DB?

Tags: java, oracle11g, apache-commons, encoder

I have few Java files in Oracle DB, these files use sun.misc.BASE64Encoder.
It looks like DBAs have recently removed support for this Encoder, I tried using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 but the class won't compile with this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED MY_SCHEMA."MyAPI" AS
//import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder; this is deprecated
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;  // this also doesn't work
```

What is the drop in replacement of sun.misc.BASE64Encoder that can be used within Oracle DB ? Please note that I don't have admin access to DB. 
Thank you for your inputs.

**EDIT:** This is not the same question as suggested by mods, my java class are stored in Oracle DB and I don't have privileges to add/remove libraries in Oracle. Request to please re-open this question.

Comment: Have you added commons codec jar to your classpath?

Comment: Yes, its there in my classpath, but since the java class is stored in Oracle, I don't think it will help.